# Trying to set up shipping address for buyers

Tags: php, paypal, sandbox

I'm trying to set up a button that offers buyers the option of inserting multiples 
of an item and forces them to enter a shipping address here's the code:

```
 <form action="<?php echo($paypal_url); ?>" method="post"> 
 <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. --> 
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo($paypal_email_address); ?>"> 

 <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. --> 
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> 

 <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. --> 
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo($item_name3); ?>"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo($item_price3); ?>">  
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo($item_currency3); ?>"> 
 <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo($mask); ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="undefined_quantity" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo($paypal_return); ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="notify_url"value="http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/ipn2.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo($cancel_return); ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">

 <!-- Display the payment button. -->
 <input type="image" src="/img/PocketMask.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online." />
```

I'm in the process of testing it in the sandbox and the quantity option works fine but there doesn't appear to be an option for shipping address, if anyone could help me with this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: fyi you dont need to use echo like echo($var) just use like echo $var;

Answer (score 0):

The `no_shipping` variable determines whether or not you receive the shipping address with the transaction details after a payment completes. There isn't a shipping address field that would appear on the checkout page. The buyer would need to log into their account to select the shipping address to use to complete the payment.